# Open part of html page in UIWebView

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

guys.
I want to load only part of web page, but I can't do it.

Man from Russian forum told, that I can use PHP, but I can't create this in my iOS app.
He send this code:

```
>     <?php
>     $url = "http://www.shesterenka.com";
>     $unique_start = "<h1>";
>     $unique_end = "</h1>";
>     function weather($url, $unique_start, $unique_end) {
>     $code = file_get_contents($url);
>     preg_match('/'.preg_quote($unique_start,
>     '/').'(.*)'.preg_quote($unique_end, '/').'/Us', $code, $match);
>     return $match[1];
>     }
>     echo weather($url, $unique_start, $unique_end); ?>
```

Thank you very much.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a worked example for you. It uses [All See Interactive](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to make the HTTP request.

In the header file I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

@interface testViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    UIWebView *webView;
}
@end
```

And in the implementation file I have:

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.shesterenka.com"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    self.view = webView;
}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    NSString *unique_start = @"<h1>";
    NSRange i = [responseString rangeOfString:unique_start];

    NSString *unique_end = @"</h1>";
    NSRange j = [responseString rangeOfString:unique_end];

    if(i.location != NSNotFound && j.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *weather = [responseString substringFromIndex:i.location];
        weather = [responseString substringToIndex:j.location];

        [webView loadHTMLString:weather baseURL:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"strings not found");
    }
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What part you want to load on UIWebView? If you know what content needs to be displayed on webView then load with loadHTMLString method. for example:

```
NSString* content = @"Hello World";
NSString* beforeBody = @"<html><head></head><body>";
NSString* afterBody = @"</body></html>";

NSString* finalContent = [[beforeBody stringByAppendingString:content] 
                                       stringByAppendingString: afterBody];

[webView loadHTMLString:finalContent baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't loading part of a web page, it is loading the entire html and returning part of it.

`$code = file_get_contents($url);` is reading the entire URL's html.